# Local adminhtml.xml does not work in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to modify the following core-file:

**/app/code/core/Mage/AdminHtml/etc/adminhtml.xml**

So I thought I could copy this file into:
**/app/code/local/Mage/AdminHtml/etc/adminhtml.xml**

or...

**/app/code/community/Mage/AdminHtml/etc/adminhtml.xml**

but it does not work.

Why? And what is the proper way of edit this file without touching the core files?

Answer (score 1):

The adminhtml.xml is a configuration file, configuration files are all collected and added into a single configuration file, so overwriting it like a block or layout does not work.

You usually do not edit xml core files but simply add to them by adding your own adminhtml.xml file into your custom module.